# Android Layer-list Badge

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I followed this article : http://javarticles.com/2015/09/android-icon-badge-example-using-layer-list-drawable.html . My code is almost exactley the same , with a little tweaking in the positioning part.Regardless what i try it never draws above the first layer drawable height.

I am trying to use this on an ActionBarSerlock drawer toggle button(yuh i know ABS is @Deprecated) or also known as hamburger, but how am i to set the circle to draw outside the bounds of the first image?I always get something like this:

[image]

I want the circle to draw fully and not be cut by the height of the first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `LayerDrawable` method `setLayerInset()` .Took me some time to play around , now it looks like this:

```
mLayerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 0, vSeperator, hSeperator, 0);
mLayerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 0, 0, 0, vSeperator);
```

Where the `vSeprator/hSeparator` are density independent calculated values:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int vSeperator = (int) (10 * density + 0.5f);
            int hSeperator = (int) (10 * density + 0.5f);
```

*Hint: I'm shifting both images in equal of size but opposite directions*